# Webserver isn't loading clientside after server reboot

Tags: centos7

After a Server reboot, my website isn't loading. It will try to connect but only shows a white page. I also noticed I got an error log.

http://pastebin.com/jLctqkT1

And also, here is my httpd config.

http://pastebin.com/vZLAaueg

Comment: The last 2 lines of your log states that apache starts normally... Nothing erroneous jumps out to me, assuming you were the one doing the frequent restarting. You'll need to do more debuggig than just using your webbrowser i.e. Can you see the expected results when you run a `wget http://example.com/page` from the host itself.

Comment: @HBruijn http://puu.sh/iGZI3/c6af3ceea5.png is what I get

Comment: That shows you the web server is both running (you can connect) and responding (The index document is downloaded) - intermediate conclusion: the web server is most likely not the issue. That leaves a whole host of other pitfalls, from a proxy setting in your web browser, to DNS problems, firewall and network related problems...